# How to add new backend pool to existing azure Front door using powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-front-door

I tried below code, but it's not adding new backend pool to existing front door.

```
$backend1 = New-AzFrontDoorBackendObject -Address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -httpPort 80 -httpsPort 443 -Priority 1 -Weight 50 -BackendHostHeader xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -EnabledState Enabled

$AzSubscription = Set-AzContext

New-AzFrontDoorBackendPoolObject -ResourceGroupName -Name "rndbackendpool" -FrontDoorName "rnd-test" -Backend $backend1 -LoadBalancingSettingsName "rndLB" -HealthProbeSettingsName "rndHP" -DefaultProfile $AzSubscription
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check my PS script uploaded to the gallery: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Update-existing-Azure-23a36fce